# This IMG links to a file with the wrong MIME type for an image while running SortSite on this application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am developing web app using JSP,HTML,JavaScript and i have "img" tag to display images in headers and footers as below.

`<img src="/common/images/header.jpeg">`. I could see the image in page properly but thing is sort site reproting the error as 'This IMG links to a file with the wrong MIME type for an image'

Please help me on this(Client is not accepting the app with this small error).

Comment: is the missing closing quote also in your code?

Comment: no i missed the closing quote here, i updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to answer the HTTP-Request for the image with the proper MIME-type, like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[…]
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

So the question is: which server do you use for delivering your images? And is it well configured?

Comment: i am using WebSphere, I am having two apps both are ear files i have deployed. One is common.ear which is having all the images and other is my app.

Comment: What ever the image type i am sending, i could see the same content type. For Ex: i am sending myimage.gif, i could see the content type as Content-Type : image/gif in response.

Comment: 'Content-Language en-US
Content-Length 1811
Content-Type image/jpeg
Date Tue, 03 Sep 2013 07:51:54 GMT
Last-Modified Tue, 03 Sep 2013 06:17:01 GMT
Server WebSphere Application Server/7.0'          This is the response for that image.

Comment: Seems ok – is it the same on the server that you checked with SortSite? Can you provide me with that link you pasted over there?

Comment: Yes, i have checked on same server with SortSite. What do you mean by link( do you mean app url link?), i am using localhost.

Comment: Maybe SortSite can't handle the file extension _.jpeg_, did you try _.jpg_?

Comment: I tried with other images which are having jpg extenstion, still i am getting the Content-Type image/jpeg in response even i put image.jpg. SortSite also showing the same errors.

Comment: Well then I'd infer that SortSite is not working properly. Try to tell your customer you verified the error manually and everything is fine. (: